# Laravel - shopping cart. products gets overwritten

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I have a problem with showing my products in a list, the first product always get overwritten(only qty works fine). I don't know whats wrong must be an issue in the foreach loop.................................................................................................................................................... ?

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
            <ul class="list-group">
                @foreach($products as $product)
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <span class="badge">{{ $product['qty'] }}</span>
                        <strong>{{ $product['item']['title'] }}</strong>
                        <span class="label label-success">{{ $product['price'] }}</span>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs dropdown-toogle" data-toggle="dropdown">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Reduce by 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Reduce All</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>


when I do dd($products), I get just one Item in the array as you can see below:
```

`

```
array:1 [▼
  "" => array:3 [▼
    "qty" => 2
    "price" => 60
    "item" => Product {#170 ▼
      #fillable: array:4 [▶]
      #connection: null
      #table: null
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      +incrementing: true
      #with: []
      #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:7 [▶]
      #original: array:7 [▶]
      #casts: []
      #dates: []
      #dateFormat: null
      #appends: []
      #events: []
      #observables: []
      #relations: []
      #touches: []
      +timestamps: true
      #hidden: []
      #visible: []
      #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
]
```

`

Comment: Can you put the result of var_dump($products) or dd($products) ?

Comment: @Nerea I edited

Comment: If you have only one product I don't understand why do you say that get overwritten, perhaps I missing something, but if $products['item'] is a Product object do `$product['item']->title`

Comment: Maybe your problem is when you get the products? If this is the case, the problem is not the foreach

Comment: @Nerea what can be the problem, if it's not the foreach?

Comment: How do you get the products? Can you put your code and an example of products table data?You have more than one product do you? :)

Comment: Can you show us your controller for this view?